# Single query to find out row count in SQL for multiple tables

Tags: sql

I have a schema named as Test which is having tables `A, B, C`.

I want to get the `count(row)` of each table in a single command.

Comment: @embert: Thanks for improving posts. But please make only substancial edits. People need to review your changes before they get approved. That takes time of the reviewers. Make it worth it and leave minor edits to the ones having enough rep to edit without needing approval. Thanks.

Comment: @juergend I'll heed it. It's a thin line sometimes between substantial and non-substantial (not in this case, though).

Comment: @embert: It is too minor in this case. A little bit of formatted is **way** too minor. If you need only a few seconds for the edit, then it is too minor.

Comment: @juergend Note however, that *a little bit* is subjective and that there were also changes in orthography and grammar.

Answer (score 1):

```
select count(*) as a_count, null as b_count, null as c_count from A
union
select null, count(*), null from B
union
select null, null, count(*) from C
```

Comment: thanks. is there any other way to find for all the tables.. instead specifically mentioning table names as A, B, C

Comment: The second column will not be named `b_count`. The column names of a UNION are determined by the first query.

Comment: suppose i have 15 tables starting from A1 to A15 and i need row count of each table.. how will i identify.. in your way, our query will be huge..

Comment: That is not really a huge query with 15 simple table selects.

Comment: And BTW having numbers in table names is almost always a bad DB design. Maybe you can overthink and change it.

Answer (score 0):

This will also work:

```
SELECT (SELECT COUNT(*) 
          FROM A       ) AS A_count, 
       (SELECT COUNT(*) 
          FROM B       ) AS B_count, 
       (SELECT COUNT(*) 
          FROM C       ) AS C_count;
```

- this way you will get your result in **one line** (instead of **three lines** with `UNION`)
- less code, 'cause you don't need all those `NULL` columns